# How do routers deal with IP packets whose source IP or destination IP is all zero?

Tags: router, ip, routing

All zero IPs are said to be unknown IPs.

I'm wondering, if the source IP or the destination IP of a IP packet is all zero, how do IP routers deal with it?

FYI: I'm doing research, and I want to use all zero IPs for a user-defined case, but I'm afraid all zero IPs are already used for other purposes in standard specifications or current router implementations.

Comment: Why are you asking? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: At what stages? What devices? Headers are empty (malformed)?

Comment: A router probably can't do anything with a packet as all zeros as the destination.  But you will see it on the local segment in DHCP requests.

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0` is a nonstandard broadcast address used by some initial implementations of TCP/IPv4. [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122) says that hosts *should* accept this destination address as "broadcast".

Comment: but In reality, it is not used by Cisco router or Huawei routers, right?

Comment: @misteryes: I don't know. I'm pretty sure it is not *sent* by such routers. But it is very possible that they *accept* this special address. Whether they do it or not, the conclusion is that this address already has special uses...